# Find a linear transformation by $\operatorname {Im}(T)=\ker(T)=\operatorname{Span}\{1-x,x-x^3\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Any hints how to find exact form of 
$$ T:\Bbb R_4[x] \to \Bbb R_4[x] $$
$$ T(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) $$
$$ a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R $$
given
$$ \operatorname {Im}(T)=\ker(T)=\operatorname{Span}\{1-x,x-x^3\}  $$

Comment: There isn't enough information to uniquely define $T$. Chose any two linearly independent elements of Span$\{1-x,x-x^3\}$ to use as images of $x$ and $x^2$ under $T$, and each such choice will define a different operator $T$ which meets the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map each of the canonical basis vectors $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ to vectors in $\mathrm{span}\{1 - x, x - x^3\}$. That is, you need to find constants $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_4$ and $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_4$ so that

$$
\begin{align*}
T(1) &= \alpha_1(1 - x) + \beta_1(x - x^3)\\
T(x) &= \alpha_2(1 - x) + \beta_2(x - x^3)\\
T(x^2) &= \alpha_3(1 - x) + \beta_3(x - x^3)\\
T(x^3) &= \alpha_4(1 - x) + \beta_4(x - x^3)\\
\end{align*}
$$

Start by using the constraint $\ker(T) = \mathrm{span}\{1-x,x-x^3\}$ to determine the constants. We have $0 = T(a(1-x) + b(x-x^3)) = aT(1) + (b-a)T(x) - bT(x^3)$. Substituting for $T(1)$, $T(x)$, and $T(x^3)$ and simplifying we get

$$
(a(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2) + b(\alpha_2-\alpha_4))(1-x) + (a(\beta_1 - \beta_2) + b(\beta_2-\beta_4))(x - x^3) = 0
$$

By linear independence of $1-x,\,x-x^3$ it follows that

$$
\begin{align*}
a(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2) + b(\alpha_2-\alpha_4) &= 0\\
a(\beta_1 - \beta_2) + b(\beta_2-\beta_4) &= 0
\end{align*}
$$

Since these equalities must hold for all $a$ and $b$ we conclude that $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_4$ and $\beta_1 = \beta_2 = \beta_4$. It remains to determine $T(x^2)$. Since $T(1),T(x),T(x^3)$ are the same vector, you need to choose $\alpha_2$ and $\beta_2$ so that $\{T(1),T(x),T(x^2),T(x^3)\}$ is a linearly independent set. One possible choice of constants is $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_4 = 1$, $\beta_1 = \beta_2 = \beta_4 = 0$, $\alpha_2 = 0$, and $\beta_2 = 1$, which gives

$$
T(1) = 1 - x,\quad T(x) = 1 - x, \quad T(x^2) = x - x^3, \quad T(x^3) = 1 - x
$$